# Angular Material + Theme Generator => Argument `$color` of `rgba($color, $alpha)` must be a color

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material

I have generated an Angular Material theme with this online-tool: http://materialtheme.arcsine.org/ and included it in styles.css. I have also recompiled node-sass.

But I am (still) getting this error:

```
  Argument `$color` of `rgba($color, $alpha)` must be a color
```

in node_modules/@angular/material/_theming.scss (line 1277, column 11). Here is the function with the problem:

```
@function mat-color($palette, $hue: default, $opacity: null) {
  // If hueKey is a number between zero and one, then it actually contains an
  // opacity value, so recall this function with the default hue and that given opacity.
  @if type-of($hue) == number and $hue >= 0 and $hue <= 1 {
    @return mat-color($palette, default, $hue);
  }

  $color: map-get($palette, $hue);
  $opacity: if($opacity == null, opacity($color), $opacity);

  @return rgba($color, $opacity);
}
```

Any idea whats wrong here? The generated styles look like this: https://github.com/arciisine/MaterialThemeGenerator/blob/master/src/styles

And I am using Material 6.4.6

Comment: the link does not work. where are you using `mat-color`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To anyone having the same problem: I updated to Angular 7.1 and it works now.